# How to tell if this function continuous from left or right at $x=0$

Tags: limits

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{x(x-1)} &: x <0 \\ \sin x &: 0 \le x < \pi/4 \\ \cos x&: x \ge \pi/4 \end{cases}$$

I am trying to understand whether this function is continuous at $x=0$ and whether is the function continuous from the left or right at $x=0$

I worked it out,

At $x=0$, $f(x)= \sin x$,

To check continuity at $x=0$, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$

Thus, evaluating the above tells me that they are continuous, now, am I right to say that the function is continuous from the left of $x=0$ ? or do I need to do calculations to know of this?

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x}=1-x/2+O(x^2)$ near $x=0.$ So try to compute: $$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x).$$

Comment: How did you show $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)?$

Comment: $f$ is automatically continuous from the right at $x=0$. You need to determine if $(\sqrt{1-x}-1)/(x(x-1))\to f(0)$ from the left. If you manage this, it is continuous.

Comment: In any even, since $\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{x}$ is the derivate $f'(0)$ for $f(x)=-\sqrt{1-x},$ I'm not sure how you got your limit.

Answer (score 1):

> I worked it out,
>
> At $x=0$, $f(x)= \sin x$,
>
> To check continuity at $x=0$, $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = f(0)$
>
> Thus, evaluating the above tells me that they are continuous

The limit is not concerned with how the function behaves at $0$ itself. It is concerned with how the function behaves *around* $0$. So the fact that $f(x) = \sin x$ at $x = 0$ itself is not useful for calculating the limit of $f(x)$ as $x\to 0$ (though it is of course useful for finding $f(0)$).

To the right of $0$, you are okay, because $f(x) = \sin x$ there as well (it changes to a different function some distance away, but that is not a problem - the limit is only concerned with the behavior near $0$, and any fixed distance away is not near $0$). $\lim_{x \to 0+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0+} \sin x = 0$.

But on the left of $0$, $f(x) \ne \sin x$, no matter how close to $0$ you are, so your claim of continuity from $f(x) = \sin x$ is not justified. To the left we have, $$\lim_{x \to 0-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}-1}{x(x-1)} = \frac 12$$
(Perhaps the lowest level method to find that limit is to multiply top and bottom of the fraction by $\sqrt{1-x} + 1$ and simplify.)

It should have already been shown in your class that for any $a$ and function $g(x)$ $$\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L\text{ if and only if }\lim_{x\to a-} g(x) = L\text{ and }\lim_{x\to a+} g(x) = L$$

That is, if the two-sided limit converges to a value $L$, then each of the one-sided limits must also converge to that same value $L$. And conversely, if the two-one sided limits converge to the same value $L$, then so does the two-sided limit.

But in this case, $\lim_{x\to 0-} f(x) = \frac 12$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x) = 0$. These are not the same. So $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ cannot converge. And because it does not converge, it certainly isn't equal to $f(0) = 0$.

Had $f(x)$ actually been continuous at $0$, then it would have automatically been both right and left continuous at $0$, and your problem would have been done. But it isn't continuous there, so you will need to examine the one-sided continuities separately.